# Re-run the application on file changes using exec-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, exec-maven-plugin

I have a maven based application which I run with `mvn compile exec:java` using the exec-maven-plugin. How can I configure it so that the application restarts when there are file changes detected?

Comment: will hot reload help you somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If  `maven-compiler-plugin:compile` compiles changed sources it creates the file `.../target/maven-status/maven-compiler-plugin/compile/default-compile/createdFiles.lst`.

You can put your `exec-maven-plugin` into a [Maven profile](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) and activate it by `<file>/<exists>`.